# SharePoint 365 - Site Templates

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

I've recently create a site template on our SharePoint online environment which did originally have site publishing features enabled. This was done by setting the appropriate flag to enable saving as a template and then using the url /_layouts/15/savetmpl.aspx to save it.

When creating a site from this template i get intermittent errors indicating something went wrong but with no further detail other than a correlation ID. It's not every time and it happens occasionally when using the site.

A couple of questions on this.

a) What with the publishing infrastructure is not supported within Site Templates.

b) What is the best approach to create a custom site template where i can have a custom front page containing web parts and content, based on the publishing page layouts. I've searched through a significant number of posts online and cannot find a definitive answer to this.

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Grant

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps to create Site using custom template :

1.Firstly create site using custom template and select "**upload site template later**" or "**upload solution later**".

2.Then go to your created site and firstly enable publishing feature before uploading your site template to the solution gallery.

3.After that just go to the "**Solutions**" under "**Web Designer Galleries**" and upload your "**Site template**".

4.Now go to Site settings and select "**Sites and workspaces**" under "**Site Administration**".

5.And you can create your Custom site. you can see your uploaded Site template in **Custom tab**

Feel free to ask question if you have any doubt.